# Handling expired cookie in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, cookies, angular, observable

I am experimenting with Angular 2 and trying to use document.cookie as my access-token storage.

What I have done is I set a cookie with an accesstoken & expiration of 30 mins. Now the application will set the cookie on load so subsequent api process handle pretty well till 30 mins. My problem is i want to check if cookies is expired and then fetch new accesstoken set it to the cookie and call respective method.

Here's my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Operator} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AccessToken } from './access-token.service';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {  

  constructor(
      private _accessToken : AccessToken,
      private _http: Http
  ) {}

  request(url:string){
      var token = this._accessToken.readCookie();
      return this._http.get(url,{
          headers : new Headers({
              "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token
          })
      })
          .map(data => data.json().result)
          .catch(this._handleError)

  }

  fetchData(dataurl:string){
     var token = this._accessToken.readCookie();

     if(!token){        
        this._accessToken.getToken()
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this._accessToken.setCookie(response);                  
                }
            )
            // I want to call this.request() after the accesstoken has been set to the document.cookie

      } else {
            return this.request(dataurl)
      }
  }

  getAllProducts(){
      return this.fetchData('https://localhost/api/products');
  }


  private _handleError (error: Response) {
      console.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

The `this._accessToken.getToken()` method make a http.post request to an endpoint and gets an accesstoken.
The `this._accessToken.setCookie()` method then sets a document.cookie with the accesstoken and expiration time of 30 mins.

I'm not sure how i go about sequencing the `fetchData()` method incase of cookie expiration so that it first gets accesstoken sets it to cookie then only calls the `request` method.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't sound like a secure solution. I think you should prefer something like Angular2 JWT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDHihQ5hB5I) where the JS in the client is not even able to access the token but it's still sent with each request to the server. See also https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-jwt, https://auth0.com/blog/introducing-angular2-jwt-a-library-for-angular2-authentication/ (don't know what package is the best for TS because I'm only using Dart myself).

Comment: I think so too. This is just an experimental thing. After thinking a bit since the process is for authentication, do you think its a good idea if i make the api call request synchronous. And do you know how do i make the http.get synchronous??

Comment: There is no way to make it sync.

Comment: Too bad. So any idea how should I tackle this scenario, so that i can check for expired cookies before any calls. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

just move the call inside the `subscribe(...)` callback

```
if(!token){        
    this._accessToken.getToken()
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                this._accessToken.setCookie(response);                  
                // I want to call this.request() after the accesstoken has been set to the document.cookie
            }
        )

  } else {
```